# how to Avoid composer for php packages?

Tags: pdf, composer-php, file-conversion, phpword

I'm working on some project with file conversion `docx to pdf`, and i use shared host server which dont have a `ssh` connection, only option to use is `Ftp`.

So is there any option to extract package as a library without using composer, like `phpword`, its portable and can be basicly copied in server folder, but converter packages are only availabe with `composer`. 
I have tried to extract needed files from package, but seems they in core need autoloader.php and only option i see is just modifying source files for portable use.

Is there option how to do it easier, if thats posible?

I'm new with `composer` which makes me hard to understand posibility of extraction packages for portable use.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Why **exactly** don't you want to use Composer? Anything not working when you install that library locally and deploy it using FTP or anyhting else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## The composer dependency

Yes, I ran into this 'composer' problem as well. Lots of developers seem to like it, for various reasons, but, if you want to try out a small package, or you only have FTP access, it just introduces another dependency. For big frameworks I can understand this, but for a small piece of code, with few classes, it makes no sense.

Example: I wanted to output an Excel file in ODS format, and found a relatively simple piece of code to do that:

https://github.com/Lapinator/odsPhpGenerator

Unfortunately the latest version depends on composer. No other way to use the code is provided. The developer probably sees this as an advantage? Well, I don't. So what to do? Be forced down the composer path, or hack the code a bit?

The latter can be a lot simpler than you might think. All we need is the content of the **autoload.php** file. This file will probably tell PHP where to find the classes of the package using SPL functions. You can try to write your own autoloader, but my package needs all its php files, so I simply wrote this:

```
require_once('../src/ods.php');
require_once('../src/odsDraw.php');
require_once('../src/odsFontFace.php');
require_once('../src/odsStyle.php');
require_once('../src/odsTable.php');
require_once('../src/odsTableCell.php');
require_once('../src/odsTableColumn.php');
require_once('../src/odsTableRow.php');
```

After adding that as the **autoload.php** to the package it worked without using composer.

In my opinion a developer should provide a way to try such a small package without having to go through the composer process. They probably don't do this because they want to do things 'the right way'. And, of course, once you're used to composer it is no big deal.

Comment: I recently wrote my own autoload.php file, which was the only way to make package working without using composer. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can exec `composer install` on your computer and than copy all files to server. `vendor` folder contains all composer dependencies.

Comment: So i have tryed to install all packages with composer, and i got problem with classes, that they can't be found, and as i include class php path its says i have dublicate. Is something wrong with composer or package itself?

Comment: You should remove vendor folder, then execute `composer install` and require `vendor/autoload.php` in code.

Answer (score 0):

Note that Composer is NOT a library installer. It is not supposed to be run on the production server while everyone is waiting for the site to come back up after an update.

I'd argue that a hosting company that only offers FTP access probably should not get your money (due to security reasons, your password is transmitted in clear text, for everyone to read), but when it comes to Composer, you don't need SSH on the server, only on your local machine.

Make sure you are running the same PHP version both locally and remotely, or you'll install libraries that cannot be used with the remote PHP version.

Comment: It's university project work, so yeah, i dont want to spend money on server, which is gona be used for few months...